# Wi-Fi Access Point has very low speed in one direction

Tags: wifi, embedded, hostapd, access-point

We are creating an Access Point on an embedded device by using hostapd and dnsmasq. No iptables rule is set.

We set it on 5Ghz (a/n) however max transfer speed is 6.1 Mbyte/sec. (Tried with scp and http -plus multi file)

Wifi module is RTL8822CS and hostapd.conf file is like below:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
hw_mode=a
channel=48
ieee80211d=1
country_code=FR
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1         
wmm_enabled=1

ssid=SOMESSID
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=SOMEPASS
```

When i test with iperf:

```
#in device 
iperf -s
#in laptop
iperf -c 192.168.35.17 -f M  -t 50 -i 1
```

i got this results:

```
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  13.8 MBytes  13.8 MBytes/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  14.8 MBytes  14.8 MBytes/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  12.4 MBytes  12.4 MBytes/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  12.6 MBytes  12.6 MBytes/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  12.6 MBytes  12.6 MBytes/sec
```

but when i run iperf server on my laptop and iperf client in device, results changes:

```
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  3.38 MBytes  3.38 MBytes/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  5.00 MBytes  5.00 MBytes/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  6.75 MBytes  6.75 MBytes/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  6.75 MBytes  6.75 MBytes/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  6.62 MBytes  6.62 MBytes/sec
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  6.00 MBytes  6.00 MBytes/sec
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  5.88 MBytes  5.88 MBytes/sec
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  7.38 MBytes  7.38 MBytes/sec
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  5.75 MBytes  5.75 MBytes/sec
[  3]  9.0-10.0 sec  6.75 MBytes  6.75 MBytes/sec
```

What can cause this?

Comment: The WLAN chip is connected via SDIO? The SDIO clock is supposed to be correct if transmitting speed is okay. A possible reason for different speeds incoming and outgoing  could be misconfigured DMA for the SDIO. What is the CPU load for both `iperf` scenarios?

Comment: @Philippos

Yes using SDIO and changed the max freq of SDIO within device tree, confirmed change is applied but still same result.

iperf -s CPU load is double of iperf -c in the device.

I will check the DMA.